# 'The method '_addFromInteger' was called on null' when using fold method in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, fold

I have a list of products as such:

```
wastedProducts = [product1, product2, product3, etc]
```

Each product has an attribute called `amountWasted` which is an `int`.

I am trying to sum the `amountWasted` attributes for every product in the list using the `.fold()` method as such:

```
 _wastedCount = wastedProducts
              .where((p) => p.masterCat == productHeld.masterCat)
              .fold(0, (amountWasted, product) => amountWasted + product.amountWasted);
```

I am getting the following error:

```
The method '_addFromInteger' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: _addFromInteger(0)
```

I have checked that all the items in the list have an `amountWasted` attribute =! null. I have also tried changing the initial value but get the same error.

The list also definitely contains items even after the `.where()` method, although even if it didn't contain any items I would still expect it to return 0 rather than an error.

Comment: do you have method called _addFromInteger? because i runed your code and its work

Comment: @merym no I don't, I assumed its something built into dart/flutter that is used in the .fold method

Comment: `_addfromInteger` is an internal method that is an implementation for integer addition. If you are getting that error, one of the `product` objects in `wastedProducts` has a null `amountWasted`.

Comment: Damn just realised I hadn't updated the stream to provide the amountWasted attribute. Amended it and it is now working. Thanks for the help confirming the above was actually correct